# How to optimise search

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, optimization

Given multiple options, I need to select n of them, 
such that the total rating is maximized, but the total cost 
does not exceed the budget.

```
var options = [
    { rating: 8, cost: 6, },
    { rating: 5, cost: 4, },
    //...100 of these in total
];

function select(n, budget) {
    //TODO: Replace this code with some real implementation
    return options.slice(0, 5);
}

//Sudocode:
var result = select(5, 25);
Assert(result.length == 5);
Assert(sum(result.cost) <= 25);
Assert(sum(result.rating) is maximized);
```

I have tried a few different options, all variations of loops inside loops.
But of course, they perform very slowly or never return at all.

I think that just looping is never going to work, and that there must be a
fundamentally different approach to this problem.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) - so there is no known polynomial solution to it.

However, if your weights (costs) are relatively small integers, there is a pretty efficient [pseudo-polynomial solution using dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem).

Comment: Billiant.  Thanks for putting the name to it.  I know what to Google for now.